# Directive to change the string inside of a paragraph to uppercase is not working

Tags: html, angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to write a directive that turns the content of a paragraph to uppercase when you hover your mouse over it. I am not getting any errors whatsoever - it just does not work. I have written a similar code before that highlights the text to a certain color, which worked. Why wouldn't it also work when changing the text to uppercase?

**filter.component.html**

`<p appToUpperCase>String to uppercase</p>`

**to-upper-case.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector: '[appToUpperCase]'
})

export class ToUpperCaseDirective {

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {

  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter2') onMouseEnter() {
     this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

EDIT: As @Ilya Rachinsky suggested, I have changed the event name from `mouseenter2` to `mouseenter` and it still does not work.

Comment: The directive is on a p element. Do p elements have a value property. Should it not be innerText. You can give your ElementRef a type to help see what properties are on the element.  Can you log to the console to see if your event is triggered. You will also need to store the original innerText and reset it on mouseleave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive structure looks fine. I guess you forgot to include it into the list of declarations on the module, so the directive will be available for the templates. Additionally, there is no 'value' property on 'p' element, you need to use innerHTML as previously suggested.

Checkout my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uppercase-directive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fto-upper-case.directive.ts

Answer (score 1):

You have to use correct event name  - mouseenter instead mouseenter2

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have initially changed it to mouseenter2 because I thought that, if there's another event with the same name, it might not work. So, yeah, it does not work with mouseenter.

Comment: I just checked
there is the solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzpsqa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupper-directive.ts
need to update innerHTML property